# Correct Read-only Firestore rules for an iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an iOS application which uses **Firestore** for getting some data. My app only reads data, never writes.
At the moment I don't use **Firebase Authentication**. I've set rules in **Firestore**: `allow read: if true`, but they send me an email with warnings every day: "Database is available for reading for all users".

1. So my question is: what approach should I use in my case? If I want to protect the data and minimise the risk of someone (not from my app) can get access to the database.
2. I don't want users to register. For example I can create one account in **Firebase Authentication** and give permission to it for reading data in **Firestore**: `allow read: if request.auth.uid == "some id"` and use this account for each user in the app. But more likely there are some limitations for large amount logged in devices with one account (e.g. some number of log in for one account per a minute), aren't they?
3. Also I heard about **Firebase App Check** which protects API resources from abuse by preventing unauthorised clients from accessing your backend resources (via DeviceCheck or App Attest on Apple platforms). Should I use it in my case?

Comment: You should use [anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)

Comment: @trndjc thank you very much for help. I can add that in the Firestore support they suggested me the same actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To silence the email notifications, try removing the global read rule and replacing it with a read-allow rule collection by collection, such as the following.

```
match /someCollection/{doc} { allow read; }
match /anotherCollection/{doc} { allow read; }
```

Get as granular as you can about these rules for read and write.

As to your other questions, if your app doesn't make use of user accounts then don't use Firebase Auth. I would avoid using one auth account for all app users; this just doesn't make sense in the big picture. There is nothing wrong with an app that has global read access to everyone. And if you have security concerns, just opt into App Check.